# QTcpServer not working

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a TCP server in C++ with QT. I have the code but as soon as I try to connect to the server with SocketTest it says connection refused (most likely due to the server not running).

This is in my tcplistener.h:

```
#ifndef TCPLISTENER_H
#define TCPLISTENER_H

#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>

class tcp_listener : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
public slots:
    void newConnectionFromServer()
    {
        QTcpSocket* newConnection = nextPendingConnection();
        qDebug("New connection from %d", newConnection->peerAddress().toIPv4Address());
    }
public:
    tcp_listener(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QTcpServer(parent)
    {
        listen(QHostAddress::Any, 30000);
        connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection()),    SLOT(newConnectionFromServer()));
    }
};

#endif // TCPLISTENER_H
```

This is in my engine.h:

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "tcplistener.h"

class engine
{
public:
    void init()
    {
        qDebug("Initializing AuraEmu...");

        tcp_listener list();
    }
};

#endif // ENGINE_H
```

And this is my main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "engine.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    engine eng = engine();
    eng.init();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: What's the context of those 2 lines of code? Does your object go out of scope immediately? I notice you create it on stack instead of on the heap so it will be destroyed as soon as you leave the block, unless you have a nested event loop.

Comment: My question contains all code. I call the function which calls those 2 lines in my entry point. I'm not 100% used to C++ so things might work different than in languages like C# and Java.

Comment: I suspect that you don't have much experience with unmanaged languages and that will be a **real problem** for you in C++. You really need a solid understanding of what the difference between stack and heap is. You know, as in "if all else fails, read the manual".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer, and my comment before that already cover what you did wrong, so I'll just supply the solution.

I've added comments because you said you come from Java and C#, but really, don't try to program C++ like it's Java or C#, because it's not.

```
class engine
{
public:
    void init()
    {
        qDebug("Initializing AuraEmu...");
        tcp_listener *list = new tcp_listener(); // Allocate on the heap instead of the stack.
    }

    ~engine()
    {
        delete list; // C++ is an UNMANAGED language, there is no garbage collector
    }
private:
    tcp_listener *list; // This is a pointer to an object.
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'll go and learn some more about stack and heap, I've gotten it at school but it kind of slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
eng.init();
```

here you create

```
 tcp_listener list();
```

and after eng.init() finished you detroy it, because
it is object on stack.

Comment: I try putting it in the class itself as a variable but then I get the following error:

/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork/qtcpserver.h:102: error: 'QTcpServer::QTcpServer(const QTcpServer&)' is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QTcpServer)
                    ^